# Group items per specific field inside the for loop (no sql)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, for-loop

I want to group returned items by the field "TimeName", So I don't want the field TimeName repeated in each line, code is below :

```
@foreach (var item in Model) {


      tim = item.MealTime;


 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TimeName)
<text> , </text>        
   @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MealTime)

        <br />      
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FoodName)
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Quantity)
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FoodUnit)

            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MealDate)
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MealTimeSpecific)
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IsActive)
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InsertDate)
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InsertUser)

    <br />
 }
```

I have tried to make nested for loop but it doesn't work, is there are any way to fix that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution but I hope to have better one,

```
 @{
      tim = Model.FirstOrDefault().MealTime;
  }

     @Model.FirstOrDefault().TimeName
    <br />

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    if (tim != item.MealTime)
    {
 @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.TimeName)
        <br />
}

    tim = item.MealTime;


          @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MealTime)
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FoodName)
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Quantity)
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.FoodUnit)

            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MealDate)
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.MealTimeSpecific)
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.IsActive)
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InsertDate)
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.InsertUser)

    <br />

}
```

Comment: I will not accept my answer as "accepted Answer" if someone found any solution could work, please try